# Passing data and verifying api call

Tags: reactjs, axios, next.js, react-props

I am working on a Next.js application that uses a form to capture a user zip code within state. I am trying to pass the zip code value as a prop from the parent component(Form.js) to the child (Forecast.js). This approach does not appear to be working. The goal is to get the data passed to the Forecast component so that I can make the api call. I was hoping someone could provide some suggestions to get the data passed down.

Please note the data is not being passed and the call to the endpoint is not working either.

Form.js

```
import React from 'react'

import Forecast from '../components/Forecast';



 export default class Form extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
   super(props)

   this.state = {
    zipCode: ''
   }
 }


handleSubmit = e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  this.setState({zipCode: ''});
}


render() {
  const{ zipCode } = this.state

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="form-group">
        <h3 className="header">Enter your Zipcode</h3>
        <input
        type="text"
        className="form-control"
        placeholder="Zipcode"
        id="inputDefault"
        value={this.state.zipCode}
        onChange={e => this.setState({zipCode: e.target.value})}
        />
      </div>
      <button type="button" className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
      <style jsx>{`
        body {
          height: 100vh;
          width: 100vw;
        }

        .header{
          color: #fff;
          font-weight: 600;
          font-family: 'Apercu', 'sans-serif';
        }
        div {
          margin-top: 300px;
        }
        @media (max-width: 600px) {
          div {
            background: blue;
          }
        }
    `}</style>
    <Forecast  zipcode={this.state.zipCode} />
    </div>
  )
}
}
```

Forecast.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';




export default class Forecast extends React.Component {

static async getInitialProps () {
  const res = await axios.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?zip=${this.props.zipcode}&APPID=6f9e2f1d20bef61a529b8dbdb3fd82ae&units=metric`);
  console.log(res.data)
  return {weather: res.data};
}

render() {
  const { weather } = this.props;

  console.log(this.props)
  return (
    <div className="container--section-two">
      <h1 className="header--section-two"> Here is your 5-day Forecast</h1>
      <div>
        <ul className="flex-wrapper">
          <li className="flex-item">1{weather}</li>
          <li className="flex-item">2</li>
          <li className="flex-item">3</li>
          <li className="flex-item">4</li>
          <li className="flex-item">5</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <style jsx>{`

        body {
          height: 100vh;
          width: 100vw;
        }

        .container--section-two{
          margin-top: 500px;
        }

        .header--section-two{
          color: #fff;
          font-family: 'Tiempos Headline', sans-serif;
          font-style: normal;
          font-weight: 300;
        }

        .flex-wrapper {
          padding: 0;
          margin: 0;
          list-style: none;

          display: -webkit-box;
          display: -moz-box;
          display: -ms-flexbox;
          display: -webkit-flex;
          display: flex;

          -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
          justify-content: space-around;
        }

        .flex-item {
          background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
          padding: 5px;
          width: 200px;
          height: 250px;
          margin-top: 10px;

          line-height: 150px;
          color: #fff;
          font-weight: bold;
          font-size: 3em;
          text-align: center;
          box-shadow: 0 2px 8px 0 #fff;
        }

        div {
          margin-top: 60px;
          margin-bottom: 250px;
        }

        @media (max-width: 600px) {
          div {
            background: blue;
          }
        }
    `}</style>
    </div>
  )
}
}
```

Comment: your code is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First up well done on getting that far! As mentioned by Sulji.Warrior, most of your code is correct.

I've knocked up a little codesandbox with some small corrections which will hopefully help you get on your way. For now, the weather response object gets printed to the console (you can open this at the bottom right):

[View on code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/k5x1pmvrro?expanddevtools=1)

The following method is the erroneous one.

```
static async getInitialProps () {
  const res = await 
  axios.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?zip=${this.props.zipcode}&APPID=6f9e2f1d20bef61a529b8dbdb3fd82ae&units=metric`);
  console.log(res.data)
  return {weather: res.data};
}
```

`getInitialProps` is the wrong 'react' method to run ajax requests from.

I'd suggest you have a read of the section of the react-docs on the component lifecycle. Specifically [componentDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) and [componentWillReceiveProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) which are made for this very purpose, and used in my codesandbox.

Best of luck!

James

Comment: This code does work however it is not working with my map function. After the data is pushed into weather:{}, I would like to iterate through it so that I can display the contents. I believe there is an issue with the rendering that will not allow this type of functionality. Any ideas???